# Problemas com variáveis de ambiente do Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Olá. Instalei recentemente o Visual Studio 2015 e começei um projeto Win32, mas sempre que vou compilar algum arquivo não pode ser localizado.

Eu fui nas propriedades do meu projeto e cliquei em `VC++ Directories`, eu percebi que há uma variável de ambiente incorreta. `$(VC_LibraryPath_x86)` possui o caminho para a pasta `C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x86` (veja a imagem 1), mas essa pasta não existe no meu computador, ao invés dela eu tenho uma outra pasta (veja a imagem 2) muito semelhante e que contém os arquivos que não estão sendo localizados.

Por que eu não tenho a pasta correta? E existe algum problema em usar a pasta que eu tenho?
Como faço para resolver esse problema?

## Imagem 1

[image: Imagem 1]

## Imagem 2

[image: Imagem 2]

Comment: Que tipo de projeto você criou? WinForms, Universal Apps, Console, etc.

Comment: É do tipo Windows Application. http://s24.postimg.org/bw6c7a3z9/201601052321.png
Não sei se o tipo de projeto tem alguma relação com o problema, mas eu tenho os arquivos necessários só que estão em uma pasta com nome diferente do esperado. Estou conseguindo compilar por enquanto por que ao invés de usar $(VC_LibraryPath_x86), estou usando o caminho completo da pasta.

Comment: Procurei esta tela aqui VS2015 e não encontrei, qual versão do VS, professional, ultimate? Qual o caminho para abrir esta tela do print?

Comment: Professional. http://s28.postimg.org/wplm3rrml/201601052333.png

Comment: Esse projeto é do tipo C++?

Comment: Sim, é do tipo C++.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33888/discussion-between-rubstackoverflow-and-jhonas-boeno).